# Rails active record order by sum of a column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have 2 Models **Posts** and **Topics**

- Posts has number of "viewed".
- Posts has a topic.

Here I want to get the most view topics and order it `DESC` (the highest total views of
all posts tagged with that topic) using rails active record. Here is my current code of what I am trying to do but it is not correct :-

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  scope :ordered, -> {
    joins(:posts).order("sum(posts.viewed) DESC").limit(2).uniq
  }
end
```

Comment: You probably need to group by `posts.id` or sth like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group your topics_id

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :posts
 scope :ordered, -> {
 joins(:posts).group("topics.id").order('SUM(posts.viewed) desc').limit(2).uniq
 }
end
```

This would work

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad pattern to sum childer and than order by the sum.

I would advise you to add a `total_views:integer` column to your Topic.rb and update it whenever the sum of post.views changes.

When a child post's `viewed` value increases, you can call a callback to automatically update the `total_views` column.

Post.rb can have something like:

```
after_create do
  topic.update_total_views
end
after_update do
  topic.update_total_views
end
after_destroy do
  topic.update_total_views
end
```

Topic.rb:

```
def update_total_views
  update_column :total_views, (posts.map(&:viewed).sum)
end
```

Than in your controller you can call `Topic.all.order(total_views: :desc)`